# Listing members of value in gdb using python api

Tags: c++, gdb, gdb-python

I'm trying to find a way to get a list of members of a c++ class object from the python api in GDB.

So far, the only solution I've been able to find has been to use the `ptype <value>` and then try to parse it for the members, and I was wondering if there's a better way that I haven't been able to find.

Comment: Member variables or functions? Member variables can be listed with [Type.fields()](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Types-In-Python.html#index-Type_002efields).

Comment: I was actually thinking of both, but right now my interest is in checking the member functions.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a value called `my_name` you can get the member variables by

```py
val = gdb.parse_and_eval('my_name') #converts it to a gdb value 

for field in val.type.fields():
        return field.name, val[field.name]
# this gives you the member name and the gdb value.
```

more information on gdb.Types [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Types-In-Python.html)

If it is member functions i am not sure how to get that